# Symfony2 Forms - Get editable elements in controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to set up an inline editable form for editing a TaskType form. I am sending a request via ajax that needs to return a json object of field names and the rendered html input/select/textarea.

However, I can't see a way of extracting the rendered html. Or, is there a way to render a form to json in twig (though this doesn't see right)?

I could just pass back the values and input type in a `JsonResponse` and render the element in JavaScript, but it would make sense to utilise the Symfony2 Form renderer.

Im looking to return something like this:

```
{ 
    title: "<input ... />",
    author: "<select ... ><option>...</option></select>"
    ...
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig holds the definition of each type of fields therefore I'd highly suggest to use the render function from Twig.

You can do something like this:

```
$formView = $this->createForm(new FormClass(), $entity)->createView(); // your form view

$json = array(); // initialize json array

foreach ($formView as $fieldKey => $field) {
    $json['html'][$key] = $this->container
                       ->get('templating')
                       ->render('formField.html.twig', array('field' => $field));
}

$json['message'] = 'Success!'; // send a success or failure message

// encode the array above into json and return it
```

And the template has a call on **{{ form_widget(field) }}** or **{{ form_row(field) }}** (to include label and error message).

Not sure if this will perform well so it's probably better to call the render function once than multiple times.

Alternative below:

```
$formView = $this->createForm(new FormClass(), $entity)->createView(); // your form view

// parameters for the template
$params = array(
    'form' => $formView
);

// render the form once
$renderedForm = $this->container
                     ->get('templating')
                     ->render('form.html.twig', $params);

$json = array(
    'message' => 'Success!' // send a success or failure message,
    'html'    => $renderedForm,
);

// encode the array above into json and return it
```

Symfony has documentation about [how to customize form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). With this doc, you will understand why you need to go through Twig.